# How to override system.menus.css

Tags: theming

`system.menus.css` has it's own styles for the menu block. How can I override this style?

Would creating a folder called CSS in my theme and adding a file `system.menus.css` override it?

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15853/how-to-override-css-for-a-core-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your css file through your themes's `.info` file

> stylesheets[all][] = myStyle.css

Comment: if i add here the name system.menus.css - will it be overrided?

Comment: no. make it unique name

Comment: so it looks like i need to override it manually writing the same class and override styles...

Comment: yes i think it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can not override css just by making a file with the same name. If you implement a theme you can for instance use the custom.css or navigation.css (in genesis theme) to override styles from the system.menu.css. If for instance someting has a border of 2px and you want no border you can add to the style `.class { boder:0 none; }`